# Total Working Hours Decrease/Increase by Week (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to make a Water Fall chart which shows Increase/Decrease in Working Hours by Week No in PowerBI.

Currently i have used "Week No." in Category and "Hours" in Y-Axis and sort the axis by Week No. but it did not show the result properly

Here is the result that i am getting now

[image: Current Output]

If you see you can observe that after 6th Week it should output the decrease bar because 7th week is less than 6th week 
What should i do to get the increase/decrease by week No. ?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is?

Comment: If you see you can observe that after 6th Week it should output the decrease bar because 7th week is less than 6th week

Comment: So, you need a measure which calculates the delta from prior week. What have you tried? An example of your table structure might help, too...

Comment: I have added my post (added Table structure)

Comment: This is slow going. What measures have you currently tried - how are you establishing `Week` and `Hours`, for example, and what have you already tried, to get the week on week delta?

Comment: I did not try Week Delta Yet
For Week No. I have created this field 
Week No. = WEEKNUM(Sheet1[Date],2)
which you can see in X axis of chart